# Cannot access json object in phonegap using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova, getjson

I have a simple json file:

```
[{"id":"0"},{"id":"1"}]
```

I'm trying to read it and parse through a simple loop:

```
$.get("simple.json", {})
    .done(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            alert(data[i].id);
        }
    });
```

In chrome browser it works well.

In phonegap app on samsung s3 mini I get infinite alert with `"undefined"` instead `id` values.

I checked in chrome dev panel and I cannot find any errors.

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Data returned by `$.get` isn't parsed as JSON.

Use this:

```
function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    // rest of the code
```

Or, use [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of `get`:

```
$.getJSON("simple.json", {})
.done(function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        alert(data[i].id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$.getJSON('your.json',function(data){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all check your code in different browsers , if there was not any problems check that jquery plugin is add correctly in your application html code, you can call simply console.log( $('body')); if the dom element selected this is not a jquery attachment problem if not place your entire html page here

Comment: This is not a answer, but a comment.